# Android Studio AVD does not run

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

I have a very weird and incomprehensible issue with my android studio. I used to work with Android studio on my windows computer just fine, studio, AVD all were working just fine. A few days ago I had to install kali on a virtual machine on my that windows computer. Since then my android studio started weird behave. When I wanted to run AVD an error comes and say

> Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings, ensure that your Linux
>   distro has working KVM module.

but this is a windows 10 machine. After installing (again) HAXM error is gone however still I cannot open my AVD or in SDK manager I cannot click on Tools or any other option. I reinstalled Studio at least 10 times, but problems insist. 
My computer runs on intel core i-7 with 16 GB memory as well as Intel HD 520 and NVIDIA Geforce 940M with 2 GB memory.

I tried all the options I can find in the internet nothing solved anything. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, You've enabled `VT-x` in your `BIOS configuration` of your PC.

If it's not then follow

1. Restart system
2. Keep pressing `esc` key while starting to enter the recovery mode
3. Choose `BIOS Option`
4. Search for the `VT-x` or `Virtual Technology`, It'll be in `security` or `Advance` tab based on the system config
5. enable that.

Then try AVD in `android studio`. In my case it resolved my problem.